# mvn spring-boot:run results in java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a project that runs fine with I run it as an executable JAR. 
However, when I use `mvn spring-boot:run` I get the following error:

```
 exception in thread "Thread-129" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) previously initiated loading for a different type with name "org/test/DefaultIdAndText"
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.ClassUtil.getDeclaredFields(ClassUtil.java:1055)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector._findFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:66)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collect(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:41)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedFieldCollector.collectFields(AnnotatedFieldCollector.java:36)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass._fields(AnnotatedClass.java:349)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.AnnotatedClass.fields(AnnotatedClass.java:321)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector._addFields(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:379)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.collectAll(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:308)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.POJOPropertiesCollector.getJsonValueAccessor(POJOPropertiesCollector.java:196)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.introspect.BasicBeanDescription.findJsonValueAccessor(BasicBeanDescription.java:251)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BasicSerializerFactory.findSerializerByAnnotations(BasicSerializerFactory.java:346)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory._createSerializer2(BeanSerializerFactory.java:216)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.BeanSerializerFactory.createSerializer(BeanSerializerFactory.java:165)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1389)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider._createAndCacheUntypedSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:1336)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:510)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.SerializerProvider.findTypedValueSerializer(SerializerProvider.java:713)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.DefaultSerializerProvider.serializeValue(DefaultSerializerProvider.java:308)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._configAndWriteValue(ObjectMapper.java:3905)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(ObjectMapper.java:3219)
    at lambda$commit$0(EventStoreService.java:120)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(ConcurrentHashMap.java:3606)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:580)
```

I can't share the code because it is proprietary. 
I do have the same library jar dependency two times (1 directly), and 1 through another dependency.
I added an exclusion but this doesn't seem to do anything.

The strange thing is that the application runs fine, when I run the jar directly.

### Update

I also noticed the following... and I think it is the problem:

```
TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@79fe98a7
```

I will try to disable the devtools classloader and reloading.

Comment: The names which contain `test` looks strange to me in production code?

Comment: @khmarbaise It's a data migration project. Another team member named a package for one of the minor dependencies `org.test`. It's still a snapshot dependency. 
Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was spring dev tools. 
I had to remove it, and also remove it with an exclusion from any other dependencies.

I removed it by first running the following and seeing where it was located:

```
dependency:tree -Dverbose
```

And following I either commented out the dependency or added the following exclusion:

```
<exclusion>  <!-- declare the exclusion here -->
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
```

After removing it, the error went away and I now see:

```
TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader
  context: ROOT
  delegate: true
----------> Parent Classloader:
java.net.URLClassLoader@44052821
```